# Parsing file from local drive via JSP using commons-fileupload (empty List<FileItem>)

Tags: java, file, jsp, upload

I am trying to parse file from local drive (Windows 10) to server running on Linux box. The servlet is less than 3.0 version so I am using the Apache FileUpload and IO jars. I have 2 problems trying to parse the file.

The submit using `<input type = "submit" value = "Upload File" >` currently won't submit the data so I am using `<button id="ok" onclick="document.forms[0].submit();return false;">Submit</button>`.

Second and more serious problem is that I am not able to upload parsed data to  List. After I submit the form, the List is empty. I have commented out every method in jsp form so I should not read and parse the request body before the Apache upload (but I am no sure how to verify the body is not empty before I try to read the file). I have also tried to upload the text instead of file (to check if the there is problem trying to access windows file system) but with no success.

Maybe I am missing something obvious. Can you please give me some hints how to troubleshoot this. Thank you

**JSP (old file)**

```
<%@ page language="java" %>
<%@ page contentType="text/html; charset=UTF-8" %>
<%@ include file="upload_function.jspf" %>
<%String pageLanguage=getLanguage(request);%>
<%@ MultipartConfig%>
<%@WebServlet("/upload")%>

<html>
    <head>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="upload.css"></link>
    </head>
    <body>
        <form action="" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" ></form>
            <div>
                <tr>
                    <h4>Uploaded File:</h4>
                    <%=getLocalImage(request)%>
                </tr>
            </div>

<div>
                <tr>
                    <label for=""><h4>File Upload:</h4></label>
                    <input type="file" id="image" name="image" accept="image/png, image/jpeg"  >                    
                    <input type = "submit" value = "Upload File" >          
                </tr>
            </div>

            <div>
                <tr>
                    <p>
                        <button id="ok" onclick="document.forms[0].submit();return false;">Submit</button>
                        <button id="cancel" onclick="javascript:window.close();return false;">Ok</button>
                    </p>
                </tr>
            </div>
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

**JSPF (old file)**

```
<%@ page import="java.io.*" %>
<%@ page import="java.util.*" %>
<%@ page import="javax.servlet.*" %>
<%@ page import="org.apache.commons.fileupload.disk.*" %>
<%@ page import="org.apache.commons.fileupload.servlet.*" %>
<%@ page import="org.apache.commons.fileupload.*" %>
<%@ page import="org.apache.commons.io.*" %>

<%!

public String getLocalImage(HttpServletRequest request) throws ServletException, IOException 
    {
        String result = "null";
        String UPLOAD_DIRECTORY = "/final/directory/for/file/upload/";

        // Check the content
        if(ServletFileUpload.isMultipartContent(request)){
            try {
                // Create a factory for disk-based file items
                DiskFileItemFactory factory = new DiskFileItemFactory();

                // Configure a repository (to ensure a secure temp location is used)
                ServletContext servletContext = this.getServletConfig().getServletContext();
                File repository = (File) servletContext.getAttribute("javax.servlet.context.tempdir");
                factory.setSizeThreshold(40960);
                factory.setRepository(repository);

                // Create a new file upload handler
                ServletFileUpload upload = new ServletFileUpload(factory);
                upload.setSizeMax(2000000);

                // Parse the request
                try {
                    List<FileItem> items = upload.parseRequest(request);
                }
                catch(Exception ex){
                    ex.printStackTrace();
                }

                // Process the uploaded items
                Iterator<FileItem> iter = items.iterator();

                File uploadedFile = new File(UPLOAD_DIRECTORY,"picture.png");

                // List<FileItem> items is empty - error trying to use the iterator
                FileItem item = iter.next();

                item.write(uploadedFile);
                result = "file upload successful";
            }
            catch (Exception t) {
                t.printStackTrace();
                return result;
            }     
            return result;
        }
        else {
            return "not multipart";
        }
    }

%>
```

Edit:
So I think main problem was, I did not connect the jsp file with the servlet through the action attribute in the form.
I have created the functional example of the upload servlet but I would need to import the UploadServlet class into JSP file without actually using the .java project file.
I have created the jar file of the UploadServlet class and add the jar file into the WEB-INF/lib folder of the web app. But when I try to create the instance of the UploadServlet class, IDE tells me it can't be resolved to the type.

Is it possible to import the user defined class into JSP like this? Do I e.g. need some more dependencies? I am not sure what about the tomcat servlet-api.jar, the UploadServlet jar is probably trying to use it but the servlet-api classes are outside of the web app. Hovewer it is not possible to include the servlet-api.jar directly under the WEB-INF/lib web app.

**UploadServlet.java   --->    UploadServlet.jar**

```
package test.pkg;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.List;

import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

import org.apache.commons.fileupload.FileItem;
import org.apache.commons.fileupload.disk.DiskFileItemFactory;
import org.apache.commons.fileupload.servlet.ServletFileUpload;


public class UploadServlet extends HttpServlet {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    
    public UploadServlet() {
        super();
        // constructor
    }

    public void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        // doPost implementation
    }
}
```

**JSP with UploadServlet**

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=UTF-8"
    pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<%@ page import="test.pkg.UploadServlet" %>
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
<title>File Upload</title>
</head>
<body>
        <form method="post" action="UploadServlet" enctype="multipart/form-data">
            Select file to upload: <input type="file" name="uploadFile" />
            <input type="submit" value="Upload" />
            <%
                UploadServlet servletUp = new UploadServlet();
                servletUp.doPost(request, response);
            %>
        </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: `<input type="image">` is not designed to upload images, but rather to use an image as a submit button. Don't your problems get fixed if you switch it to `<input type="file">`? https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/Input/image / https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/Input/file

Comment: I am sorry for the confusion. I edited the code a little bit before posting and I wrote this line wrong (I have the file type in my code). I double checked to be sure and the problem is not in that unfortunately. But thank you for the advice anyway. I was trying to use the text type (instead of the file type) also but without no luck.

Comment: Unfortunately, I don't have time right now to properly test this and answer, but just a few pieces of advice that should help: 1. you should use `method="POST"` for your form with `enctype="multipart/form-data"`. 2. You should definitely use a Servlet to receive your form data instead of inline code in a JSP. 3. You should use JSTL rather than scriptlets for your JSP. Good luck

Comment: 4. I can't tell what `<%@ MultipartConfig%>` is for here. And I'm pretty sure you should remove `<%@WebServlet("/upload")%>` as well

Comment: I have edited the question. Do you think it is possible to import user defined servlet class in form of jar file (included in the WEB-INF/lib folder of the web app)? I would need to use the UploadServlet class without the need of the .java project file. Is it doable this way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm answering with your previous commentary in mind where you asked if the Servlet could be defined in a JSP, as you were not sure you would have access to Java classes in this project.

You can, as you have access to the request and response inside any JSP, like any other servlet (JSP is a servlet). That said, you should separate the form from the handling of its values. A generally good pattern to use is POST-REDIRECT-GET.

I'm using JSTL for the form as this is better practice.

To handle the request in another JSP, I'm forced to resort to scriptlets, which is usually a sign of bad design, but considering you can't edit Java source, no other choice...

**Page containing form: `fileUploadForm.jsp`**

Set your form to POST to another page

```jsp
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=UTF-8"
    pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<%@taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" %>

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <title>My upload file test form</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1>My upload file test form</h1>
        
        <!-- Display messages -->
        <div class="messages">
            <c:if test="${not empty sessionScope.uploadErrors}">
                <c:forEach items="${sessionScope.uploadErrors}" var="err">
                    <p class="error"><c:out value="${err}" /></p>
                </c:forEach>
            </c:if>
            <c:if test="${not empty sessionScope.uploadSuccess}">
                <p class="success">File uploaded successfully: <c:out value="${sessionScope.uploadSuccess}" /></p>
            </c:if>
        </div>
        
        <!-- Form with POST action pointing to uploadFormAction.jsp -->
        <form name="upload-test" action="./uploadFormAction.jsp" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
            <label for="upload">Upload file:</label>
            <input type="file" name="uploaded" id="upload" accept="image/png" />
            <div class="submits">
                <input type="submit" value="Send" />
            </div>
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

**JSP with data handling code: `fileUploadAction.jsp`**

Handle the POST request, record the result (errors or success), and then redirect back to your form to show them

```jsp
<%@page import="org.apache.commons.fileupload.FileItem"%>
<%@page import="java.io.File"%>
<%@page import="org.apache.commons.fileupload.disk.DiskFileItemFactory"%>
<%@page import="java.util.List"%>
<%@page import="java.util.ArrayList"%>
<%@page import="org.apache.commons.fileupload.servlet.ServletFileUpload"%>
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=UTF-8"
    pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<%
    //Storage for error messages
    List<String> errors = new ArrayList<>();
    session.setAttribute("uploadErrors", errors);
    session.setAttribute("uploadSuccess", null);

    //Check for correct form encoding
    if (!"POST".equalsIgnoreCase(request.getMethod())) {
        errors.add("Form must have method=\"POST\"");
    }
    if (!ServletFileUpload.isMultipartContent(request)) {
        errors.add("Form has no multipart data to read from");
    }
    
    if (errors.size() < 1) {
        
        try {
        
            // Create a factory for disk-based file items
            DiskFileItemFactory factory = new DiskFileItemFactory();
    
            // Configure a repository (to ensure a secure temp location is used)
            ServletContext servletContext = this.getServletConfig().getServletContext();
            File repository = (File) servletContext.getAttribute("javax.servlet.context.tempdir");
            factory.setRepository(repository);
    
            // Create a new file upload handler
            ServletFileUpload upload = new ServletFileUpload(factory);
            upload.setSizeMax(4L * 1024 * 1024);
    
            // Parse the request
            List<FileItem> items = upload.parseRequest(request);
            String found = null;
            
            for (FileItem item : items) {
                if (item.isFormField()) {
                    //Process other fields in form
                } else if ("uploaded".equals(item.getFieldName())) {
                    if (item.getSize() > 0) {
                        if (found != null) {
                            errors.add("Only one file allowed");
                        } else {
                            found = item.getName();
                            File uploadedFile = new File("./uploads/","picture.png");
                            if (uploadedFile.exists()) uploadedFile.delete();
                            item.write(uploadedFile);
                        }
                    }
                } else { //Other file field
                    //Ignore it ? error ?
                }
            }
            if (found == null) {
                errors.add("No uploaded file !");
            }
            session.setAttribute("uploadSuccess", found);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            //Should log it and return it in a more readable form
            errors.add(e.getMessage());
        }
        
    }
        
    response.sendRedirect("uploadFormPage.jsp");

%>
```

Now considering your question edits, if you have your `Servlet` class already defined and want to call it from a JSP, then I suppose you could use the same principles as described here, and create a new intance of the servlet to call its `doPost` Method where you get the POST request, but that's supposing your servlet is stateless and doesn't use init parameters from web.xml...

**How you should do it if you *can* write a Servlet**

1. Keep the same form code, just change the destination of your `<form>` to `action="<c:url value ="/uploadFile" />"`
2. Create your Servlet with url pattern set to "/uploadFile" to handle the POST (e.g. using `@WebServlet` annotation), and same code as fileUploadAction.jsp

```java
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import javax.servlet.ServletContext;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.annotation.WebServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpSession;

import org.apache.commons.fileupload.FileItem;
import org.apache.commons.fileupload.disk.DiskFileItemFactory;
import org.apache.commons.fileupload.servlet.ServletFileUpload;

@WebServlet("/uploadFile")
public class FileUploadServlet extends HttpServlet {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Override
    protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        HttpSession session = request.getSession();
        //Storage for error messages
        List<String> errors = new ArrayList<>();
        session.setAttribute("uploadErrors", errors);
        session.setAttribute("uploadSuccess", null);

        //Check for correct form encoding
        if (!"POST".equalsIgnoreCase(request.getMethod())) {
            errors.add("Form must have method=\"POST\"");
        }
        if (!ServletFileUpload.isMultipartContent(request)) {
            errors.add("Form has no multipart data to read from");
        }
        
        if (errors.size() < 1) {
            
            try {
            
                // Create a factory for disk-based file items
                DiskFileItemFactory factory = new DiskFileItemFactory();
        
                // Configure a repository (to ensure a secure temp location is used)
                ServletContext servletContext = this.getServletConfig().getServletContext();
                File repository = (File) servletContext.getAttribute("javax.servlet.context.tempdir");
                factory.setRepository(repository);
        
                // Create a new file upload handler
                ServletFileUpload upload = new ServletFileUpload(factory);
                upload.setSizeMax(4L * 1024 * 1024);
        
                // Parse the request
                List<FileItem> items = upload.parseRequest(request);
                String found = null;
                
                for (FileItem item : items) {
                    if (item.isFormField()) {
                        //Process other fields in form
                    } else if ("uploaded".equals(item.getFieldName())) {
                        if (item.getSize() > 0) {
                            if (found != null) {
                                errors.add("Only one file allowed");
                            } else {
                                found = item.getName();
                                File uploadedFile = new File("./uploads/","picture.png");
                                if (uploadedFile.exists()) uploadedFile.delete();
                                item.write(uploadedFile);
                            }
                        }
                    } else { //Other file field
                        //Ignore it ? error ?
                    }
                }
                if (found == null) {
                    errors.add("No uploaded file !");
                }
                session.setAttribute("uploadSuccess", found);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                //Should log it and return it in a more readable form
                errors.add(e.getMessage());
            }
            
        }
        
        response.sendRedirect("uploadFormPage.jsp");
    }

}
```